# Strange behavior when trying to use laptop as a access point

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-sharing, netsh, connectify

I have a windows7 installed laptop connected to a wired internet connection. I want my Android phone to access internet via laptop using wifi. I installed `Connectify`, but when I click `Start Hotspot` the machine screen becomes black and automatically restarts the laptop.

Then I tried following this article ([http://www.ishanarora.com/2009/07/29/windows-7-as-a-wireless-access-point](http://www.ishanarora.com/2009/07/29/windows-7-as-a-wireless-access-point/)/).
 When I issue the first command,

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow “ssid=testssid” key=test123 keyUsage=persistent
```

I see that same black screen and immediate restart. I am using windows7 and “Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)” ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [new beta](http://www.connectify.me/download/3.0/ConnectifyInstaller_3.0_Beta2.exe)? It fixes a known BSOD bug in the Connectify network service.
If that doesn't work try this:

1. Type “network connections” in the start menu  and hit enter.
2. Right click on any local network adapter and select Properties.
3. In the list under “This connection uses the following items:” search
   for Connectify. Highlight it and click uninstall .

Comment: I think I installed the latest version. I uninstall the Connectify from the list. Then I tried the netsh command, again same issue.

Comment: If you went through the web site's download link you have the one with the bug.

Comment: Seems connectify site has only that download link. Anyway I think this issue is a windows problem. Because even if I manually execute the 'netsh' command using command line, the blue screen appears.

Comment: Clicking on  "new beta" in my post will get you the newest version which is not yet linked to on their site. As for netsh crashing, after installation Connectify becomes inextricably linked to local networking so that even when not explicitly invoked it's still having an effect on your system. But you might be right as it's entirely possible that an unrelated windows error is mimicking a known bug in the package. Whatever you discover please post it as now you've got me curious.

Comment: Above beta link gives 404 and redirects to the http://www.connectify.me/.